# Automating A MySql 5.0 query on Windows

Tags: mysql, automation, windows-server-2008

Good morning! I am currently searching for a way to automate the running of a MySQL 5.0 Query. I discovered that 5.0 does not contain Event_Scheduler which I wish it did.

My questions is besides event scheduler how can I automatically run a query (i plan to have the query output a CSV file) every 12 hours or so?

I have seen several examples of Unix, Linux based processes, but have yet to see an example for Windows (Server 2008).

Comment: windows has 'task scheduler'.

Comment: If you can't upgrade to 5.1 (which does have it) then your only option is to use an external process. Probably with the task scheduler as @MarcB has suggested.

Comment: Thanks! I will look more into a batch - task scheduler solution.